# xargs command silently fails when used in a bash alias

Tags: bash, alias, xargs

From the command line, this opens two files in my phpstorm application:

```
git diff --name-only final-migration | xargs pstorm
```

When I create an alias in my ~/.bash_profile:

```
alias ropen="git diff --name-only $1 | xargs pstorm"
```

and call it from the same directory as the successful command:

```
ropen final-migration
```

Nothing happens.. I've tried altering the alias so that it echos instead of `xargs pstorm` which works as expected. It seems like `xargs` is where the problem lies when it's being used in an alias.. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Note: I'm using OSX where things are a little different sometimes.

Comment: The aliases have "search & replace" behaviour. `bash` replaces the `ropen` alias and your command becomes `git diff --name-only | xargs pstorm final-migration`. You have to turn your alias into a function to use arguments.

Comment: @JohnHunt: Make it a function as `ropen(){ git diff --name-only "$1" | xargs pstorm ; }`

Comment: @Inian This behaved in the same way, nothing happened (yes, I re 'source'd my file too..)

Comment: I created two functions to test using a function, the same behaviour as using an alias was observed. I used a test function to make sure I wasn't going mad:
The 'test' function was just:
function test() { echo "$1" | echo ; }

Comment: Your test function is very strange. `echo text | echo` will print just a newline because `text` is send to a pipe which `echo` never reads.

Comment: Shrug, the test worked.

Comment: Don't name your test functions `test` as it is the name of both a built-in and a binary, which can lead to another `test` than yours being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with my version of xargs which is supplied with OSX. By using the GNU version, @socowi's suggestion of using a function worked just perfectly.

To install the gnu version of xargs, I did as @Benjamin W said and used homebrew to install findutils. I then added the path as suggested from installing findutils to my ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: Glad to hear your problem was resolved. Accept your own answer to mark the question as closed.

Answer (score 1):

## First Problem

Aliases do not work with parameters like `$1`. The only way for aliases to use arguments  is to put them at the end. But even if `$1` would work for aliases, your definition wouldn't work, because `"$1"` is expanded at the time of definition.
You can print the value of `"$1"` with `echo "$1"`. For me, its empty. So the alias ...

```
alias ropen="git diff --name-only $1 | xargs pstorm"
```

... would be equivalent to ...

```
alias ropen="git diff --name-only | xargs pstorm"
```

To use `$1` as intended, write a function:

```
ropen() { git diff --name-only "$1" | xargs pstorm; }
```

## Possible Second Problem

`xargs` will mangle the arguments if the printed paths contain spaces.
Assume `git diff --names-only` would print the paths `a b/c` and `x/y z`, then `xargs` would construct the command `pstorm "a" "b/c" "x/y" "z"`. None of these files exist.

To allow spaces, use `xargs -d '\n' pstorm`, this will construct the correct command `pstorm "a b/c" "x/y z"`.

Comment: Neither of your solutions are working for me, I suspect this is a failing of Apple's implementation of xargs or something like that.. I don't get an error, I just get nothing as per using an alias.

Comment: Another solution I came up with myself was to use the backtick operator, however I still had trouble getting the argument into it: eg `pstorm \`git diff --name-only "$1"\``

Comment: That would be `ropen() { pstorm $(git diff --name-only "$1"); }` and works only when the printed paths don't contain symbols like space or `*`. Can you give us the output of `ropen ...` with `ropen() { git diff --name-only "$1"; }` and `xargs --version`?

Comment: ~ ropentest master
db/migrations/20180704142923_create_supplier_terms_table.php
packages/netsuite/src/NetsuiteVendorClient.php
src/Entity/Supplier/SupplierTermEntity.php
...etc
xargs version, it won't tel me:
I just get `xargs: illegal option -- -`
I did look at the man page, it's BSD 2004 version I think?

Hard to format this in a comment, but to sum up your test ropen() function worked as expected. Xargs is some weird BSD version.

Comment: @JohnHunt You can get the GNU `findutils` that contain GNU xargs.